# Update UITableView data every second

Tags: uitableview

I have some table cells displaying different time. I want the time to be updated (just like countdown).

I tried to call `[my_table_name reloadData]` every second but the method does not invoke logics in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. How can I loop through the cells of UITableView to update its contents?

**UPDATE**: the time displayed is in form of `10 days 11:12:49` ( each cell has an expiry date, when the table is updated, the expiry date subtracts current time & calculate the time remaining , which is displayed on cell )

**UPDATE 2**: There are 2 methods to reload data. One is calling from server, one is calling the function only.

```
- (void)reloadLocal {
  [my_table_name reloadData];
}
```

and the online method is:

```
- (void)reloadFromServer {
  [self parseXML:@"URL here"];
}
- (void)parseXML:(NSString *)URL {
  // read the XML & update a NSArray containing the data
}
```

the `reloadLocal` method is called like this (in `viewDidLoad` )

```
current = [[NSDate date] retain];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(reloadLocal) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, here is the pseudo codes (too long to post all lines):

```
static NSString *identifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:identifier owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currendObj in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currendObj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (CustomCell *)currendObj;
            break;
        }
    }
// then insert data to related UIOutlet elements.
NSDate *validUntil = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:diff sinceDate:current];

NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:current toDate:validUntil options:0];

cell.lbl_day.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [conversionInfo day]];
cell.lbl_minute.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [conversionInfo minute]];
cell.lbl_second.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [conversionInfo second]];
cell.lbl_hour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [conversionInfo hour]];
```

note that `current` is an instance of current time, in data type `NSDate`.

Comment: Please show us how you are calling reloadData every second.

Comment: But how are you calling reloadLocal? Are you using an NSTimer? Please show us that code.

Comment: Also show us your cellForRow code.

Comment: And are you sure that the time is firing? Put an NSLog statement in reloadLocal to check.

Comment: the event is firing, according to NSLog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up I discovered if I update the date variable `current` in `reloadLocal`, the time displaying will automatically be updated.

Comment: Yeah, I was just noticed that too. I would suggest learning how to work with breakpoints when debugging. anyway, good luck with the rest of your app.